# After using dictonary to link keywords to definitions in a quiz how to make it always display a corrcet answer

Tags: vb.net

For a quiz I used the dictionary to link the keywords to the correct definition. The main issue im facing is how would I make it so that when a keyword is displayed that out of three definitions that one is correct in a random order each time out of a possibility of three. shown below is my code of how i did my dictionary with my definitions of how i randomised them. Its abit long winded but makes it easier for me to read :P I am a student and not the best at visual basic.

In a module i have the following code

```
Public Keywords As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Keywords File Path")
Public Answers As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Definitions File Path")
```

After this i have a main form that contains the dictionary and how i have added them and done the random for the keywords and definitions.
This is under main form

```
Public Link As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
Dim Rand As New Random
Dim KeyIndex As Integer = Rand.Next(0, 14)
Dim KeywordRand As String = Keywords(KeyIndex)
```

The random I repeated for the 3 answers for each Definition label

Under Main Form load i put the following

```
Link.add(Keywords(0), Answers(0))
Link.add(Keywords(1), Answers(1))
```

this continued for other keywords and defintions

```
Definition1.text = "a) " & AnswerRand1
```

this also repeated for the other 2 definitions

now the problem is that I want to show the definitions by them selfs. None can be the same.
Also the main issue is that I want it to show the correct definition always and it to be as one of the three definitions as a random chosen label as such.

Comment: if you will be randomizing things, you probably want to start by storing the 2 elements together in the same container.  Instead of 2 arrays (with no relation to each other) consider a dictionary or list(Of T).  That way the words and definitions can also be stored in the same file (ie `thisWord = thisDefinition`).  Arrays are very 1980s.

Comment: That was only real way I was taught how to do it so I kinda need use them the arrays seem to work. I put them into the dictionary afterwards I only really used the array for the random and to get from the file, I know it might be a longer way around from doing it.It all works fine but I just have no idea how to make them appear together and to make the randoms not clash and become the same once used.

Comment: The only way I can tell what you are saying with vague, imprecise language like `make randoms not clash` and `become the same once used` is that others with similar assignment have posted better descr.  Sounds like you have 3 or 4 things to keep together, not 2: keyword, Definition, wrong answer 1, wrong answer 2 and used/macthed so you display each only once.  You need a list(of T)  to store a class of those elements (not much different from a Dict). Storing them as dissociated items will be a nightmare.

Comment: What I mean is that once an element of the array has been used then it should not be repeated for the other definitions on the form as there are three labels that each to show individual definitions and not be the same.

Comment: ...and that is what you would need the Matched/Shown/Used flag for.